# How to update deprecated WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter with userDetailsService in Spring Boot 2.7

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, security, spring-security

WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter in Spring 2.7 is depricated.
How should I update this class:

```
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private final UserRepository userRepository;

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(
                email -> {
                    log.debug("Authenticating '{}'", email);
                    Optional<User> optionalUser = userRepository.findByEmailIgnoreCase(email);
                    return new AuthUser(optionalUser.orElseThrow(
                            () -> new UsernameNotFoundException("User '" + email + "' was not found")));
                }
        ).passwordEncoder(PasswordEncoderFactories.createDelegatingPasswordEncoder());
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()....
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

According [Spring Security without the WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter](https://spring.io/blog/2022/02/21/spring-security-without-the-websecurityconfigureradapter) it could be updated:

```
public class SecurityConfiguration {

    private final UserRepository userRepository;

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return PasswordEncoderFactories.createDelegatingPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        return email -> {
            log.debug("Authenticating '{}'", email);
            Optional<User> optionalUser = userRepository.findByEmailIgnoreCase(email);
            return new AuthUser(optionalUser.orElseThrow(
                    () -> new UsernameNotFoundException("User '" + email + "' was not found")));
        };
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()...;
        return http.build();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

// spring boot 2.7.0 + changes with spring security

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfiguration {

    @Bean
    UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {

        return new MyUserDetailsService(); // to be created
    }

    @Bean
    BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {

        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {

        DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();

        authProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService());

        authProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());

        return authProvider;
    }

    @Bean
    SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider()); 
    
        http.authorizeRequests()...;

        http.authorizeRequests().and().rememberMe().userDetailsService(userDetailsService()); // important
    
        http.authorizeRequests()...;

        return http.build();
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

https://spring.io/blog/2022/02/21/spring-security-without-the-websecurityconfigureradapter

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public InMemoryUserDetailsManager userDetailsService() {
        UserDetails user = User.withDefaultPasswordEncoder()
            .username("user")
            .password("password")
            .roles("USER")
            .build();
        return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(user);
    }
}
```